why example from vega site works with Text field and doesn't work with Date field?
good day! please help!
If we take the example Stacked Area Chart from Vega site
Open the Chart in the Vega Editor and:

do make an impute with ORDINAL field like
{
"type": "impute",
"field": "sum_count",
"groupby": ["yearmonth_date"],
"key": "series", "keyvals":["Taylor Swift"],
"method": "value",
"value": 5000
}
then the impute works and the result has been added to chart, see
pic. impute ORDINAL field

but not with imputing a DATE field
{
"type": "impute",
"field": "sum_count",
"groupby": ["series"],
"key": "yearmonth_date", "keyvals":["Mon, 31 Dec 2012 15:00:00 GMT"],
"method": "value",
"value": 1005
}


all we get is the date enclosed in quotation marks to dataset, see
pic. impute DATE field last row in a picture
so the question is: why imputing a ORDINAL field is working and DATE field is not and how to do it right?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
